# C# String.Format Input string not in a correct Format

Tags: c#, string, string.format

I'm getting an exception "Input string was not in a correct format". I don't understand why. 
I looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_), but that didn't give me any ideas.

```
       string body = string.Format(@"{
                          ""credentials"": {
                                        ""name"": ""{0}"",
                                        ""password"": ""{1}"",
                                        ""site"": {
                                        ""contentUrl"": ""{2}""
                                                  }
                                            }
                                }",Username, Password, siteName);
```

Not enough sleep and old code... I was deserializing the response but not serializing the request ‍♂️

Comment: For JSON parsing/serialization just use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Comment: It think it's due to all the extra { and } from the JSON data.

Comment: `I looked at the documentation` - please have [another look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#how-do-i-include-literal-braces--and--in-the-result-string).

Comment: Put the data into an object and then JSON serialise it rather than use string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{` and `}` have special meanings in a format string. If you want the string to contain them literally, you have to escape them by doubling them:

```
string body = string.Format(@"{{
 ""credentials"": {{
               ""name"": ""{0}"",
               ""password"": ""{1}"",
               ""site"": {{
               ""contentUrl"": ""{2}""
                         }}
                   }}
       }}", Username, Password, siteName);
```

Alternatively, as @mjwills has suggested, you can create an anonymous object and serialize this to JSON:

```
var obj = new { name = Username, password = Password, site = new { contentUrl = siteName }};
string body = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```